# Building the same env into a pex file fails with python3 but works on python2

Tags: python, python-3.x, pex

I have an extremely basic environment in python with just requests being my dependency. In python2 it builds fine into its own pex file and I can open the REPL with no issues. In a python3 environment I run into this error when I run `pex -r <(pip freeze) -o my_application.pex`

```
build/temp.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/_openssl.c:498:10: fatal error: 'openssl/opensslv.h' file not found
#include <openssl/opensslv.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
error: command 'clang' failed with exit status 1
```

Am I missing something specific? I was under the impression that wheel files largely took care of the necessary binaries.

Answer (score 0):

If you're on linux/mac, you might need to install openssl (using homebrew on mac) or libssl-dev using your linux package managers

eg. on linux
`sudo apt install libssl-dev`

on mac
`brew install openssl`
then soft-link the library files to /usr/lib for compilers to find
`sudo ln -s /usr/local/opt/openssl/include/openssl/ /usr/include/`